# Kernel died running discovery.build from google-api-python-client

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

The google cloud SDK is installed.
I'm using anaconda and Spyder:

Related installed packages:

1. python 3.5.4
2. google-api-python-client 1.6.5

running this simple code:

```
import json

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

ml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

projectID = 'projects/{}'.format('projectID')

request = ml.projects().models().list(parent=projectID)

response = request.execute()

print(json.dumps(response))
```

I receive a message: the kernel died, restarting (I translated this to english because my IDE Spyder is in other language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create other environment from start with python **3.6** and problem solved.
Trying the same code with other environments with python **3.5** trigger the same problem.

I post this because is a very strange problem and someone could get stuck with it.